# Accessing .onion sites without TOR

Tags: php, tor

Okay, so I have a search engine script, that I want to scrape .onion sites and do an index for the 'deep web' but they're only available via TOR, is there anyway I could access them? Maybe with http browser headers etc?

Comment: I'm not sure this is specifically on topic, but I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question... .onion sites are only accessible via TOR; more fundamentally, they exist as part of the abstraction provided by TOR. Do you mean you just don't want to use the TOR browser, and route all your traffic through the TOR network via a network interface which abstracts away aspects of the underlying protocol so you can make normal DNS queries for .onion sites, or...?

Comment: No, what I am saying is I want my script to connect to the .onion sites, to scrape the links and add them to my database thus creating a search engine full of deep web links that they can then visit my site via tor to connect to those links. But I can't connect to .onion sites to scrape the links because they're only available via TOR.